# Java program which execute after a specific time

Tags: java

Is there any way to add a timer in java program? I mean the code will execute only after the time complete and then repeat it-self..

Comment: Did you check the javadocs before asking?

Comment: You may also investigate the scheduling features of your OS, so that the program does not stay in memory when it is inactive.

Comment: Sounds like you want to schedule a job ... eg. cron ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `java.util.Timer` and `TimerTask` classes.

In a nutshell you create a subclass of the `TimerTask` class, implement the code you want to schedule by overriding the `run` method, then use a `Timer` instance to schedule it.

Comment: Thanks dude.. i got it